# Define a new command as a loop of existing Latex commands

Tags: macros, loops, expandafter

I want to define a new command, which is a composition of commands already defined within the \csvsimple package. Therefore I've written the following code, which correctly works for my purpose:

```
\newcommand{\myfirstcommand}{\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv} % the \csvcoli command refers to the 1st column of a csv table, \csvcolii to the 2nd column, and so on.
\newcommand{\mysecondcommand}{\myfirstcommand}
```

However, I would like to write `\myfirstcommand` as a for-loop, instead of having to manually write down the \csvcol command for all 5 columns. Therefore, I've tried this:

```
\newcommand{\myfirstcommand}{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}{
    \csname csvcol\romannumeral\i\endcsname
        \ifnum\i < 5
                \& 
        \fi
    }
}

\newcommand{\mysecondcommand}{\myfirstcommand}
```

However, the outcome of the latter code is not really equivalent to the former code. How can I solve this? Maybe I have to use `\noexpand` or `\expandafter`..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it at TeX primitive level and with simple macros:

```
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\newcount\num

\def\myfirstcommand{}\num=0
\loop
   \advance\num by1
   \ifnum\num>1 \addto\myfirstcommand{&}\fi
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\myfirstcommand\csname csvcol\romannumeral\num\endcsname
   \ifnum\num<5 \repeat

%% Test:
\message{\meaning\myfirstcommand}
```

Comment: Usual caveat for the unsuspecting reader: `\addto` is already defined in LaTeX as soon as the `babel` package is loaded. Using `\def` in LaTeX is highly not recommended.

Comment: Usual caveat for the unsuspecting reader: `\addto` is already defined in OpTeX, you needn't to define it when you are using OpTeX.

Comment: Why your comment? We can clearly see that the OP is not using OpTeX, which is why you defined `\addto`. Without any warning about possible problems, so I mentioned them.

Comment: @egreg Wipet's comment is useful. Users other than the OP find questions by search, and those other users may not have exactly the same situation as OP. It is helpful to provide additional information. If the OP had asked, "Last Tuesday, I had this problem..." would it be wrong to comment that an answer also works on Wednesday?

Comment: @rallg I beg to disagree. The comment should be in the answer (as well as mine).

Comment: @egreg Ah, I see. I did not notice that the answer and comment were by the same person. Indeed, the comment should be within the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a different kind of loop. Not with `\foreach`, for several reasons having to do with expandability and grouping.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definecsvcommand}{mm}
 {% #1 = command to be defined
  % #2 = number of columns (should be ≥ 1) 
  % we build the appropriate token list
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \csvcoli }
  % the loop will step from 2 to #2 where we also add &
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { #2 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { & \exp_not:c { csvcol \int_to_roman:n { ##1 } } }
   }
  % build the temporary command
  \cs_set:NV \__mattiap_csv_command: \l_tmpa_tl
  % finish up
  \cs_new_eq:NN #1 \__mattiap_csv_command:
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\cs_new:Nn \__mattiap_csv_command: {} % initialize

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definecsvcommand{\mycommand}{5}

\ShowCommand{\mycommand}

\stop
```

The console will show that the command is defined as expected:

```
> \mycommand=\long macro:
->\csvcoli &\csvcolii &\csvcoliii &\csvcoliv &\csvcolv .
```

The idea is to build the appropriate token list: with

```
\exp_not:c { csvcol \int_to_roman:n { ##1 } }
```

the control sequences `\csvcoli`, `\csvcolii` and so on are created, but not expanded any further in the requested `e`-expansion. After that, a temporary command is defined exploiting `\cs_new:Nn` (actually a variant thereof) and the requested command is made equal to the temporary one.

---

If just one command is needed, the code is quite simple:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \csvcoli }
\int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { 5 }
 {
  \tl_put_right:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { & \exp_not:c { csvcol \int_to_roman:n { #1 } } }
 }
 \exp_args:NNV \cs_new:Npn \mycommand \l_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

which ***might*** be simplified into

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \mycommand { \csvcoli }
\int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { 5 }
 {
  \tl_put_right:Ne \mycommand { & \exp_not:c { csvcol \int_to_roman:n { #1 } } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and could be compared with the code in other answers as far as concision is concerned. Why ***might***? Because in `expl3` it's much better to maintain a distinction between token list variables and macros/functions.

What we want to define is a command that performs some action, so it is not a container of some tokens. The fact that at the bottom line both are TeX macros is irrelevant.

Further note: using the expanded assignments `\tl_put_right:Ne` avoids doing two steps (first add `&` and then `\csvcol<suffix>`), whereas `\exp_not:c` is clear about it doing “form the control sequence name, but don't expand any further”.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\romannumeral` for driving expansion with a tail-recursive loop.

In case the loop is to be carried out inside a tabular-environment/inside an alignment, it needs to be ensured that macro arguments whose content is provided by the user are "masked" by nesting them between curly braces until the moment when the result is delivered.

Otherwise things like the alphabetic constant `` `& ``, which denotes the number 38, might erroneously be taken for a table-cell-separator, which in turn would break the `\romannumeral`-driven expansion-chain.

See, e.g., the error-messages with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\foo#1{#1}%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
arabic&roman\\
text \number38 &text \romannumeral38\\
text \expandafter\foo\expandafter{\number`&}&text \expandafter\foo\expandafter{\romannumeral`&}%
%\\text \number`&&text \romannumeral`&
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

when un-commenting the line before `\end{tabular}`.

Here is the code:

```latex
\makeatletter
% \romannumeral\commandloop{<lower bound>}%
%                          {<result gathered so far>}%
%                          {<upper bound>}%
%                          {<prefix>}{<postfix>}{<separator>}{<next separator>}
\@ifdefinable\stopromannumeral{\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00 }%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\commandloop[7]{%
  \expandafter\@firstofone\expandafter{%
    \ifnum\numexpr(#3)\relax<\numexpr(#1)\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else
  }\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {\stopromannumeral#2}{%
    \expandafter\commandloop\expandafter{%
      \the\numexpr((#1)+1)\expandafter\relax\expandafter
    }\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
        \csname#4\romannumeral\numexpr(#1)\relax#5\endcsname
      }{\stopromannumeral#2#6}%
    }{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}{#7}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\myfirstcommand}{%
  \romannumeral\commandloop{1}{}{5}{csvcol}{}{}{&}%
}%
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\mysecondcommand}{\myfirstcommand}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter\mythirdcommand\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\commandloop{1}{}{5}{csvcol}{}{}{&}%
}%
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\commandloop{1}{}{5}{csvcol}{}{}{&}%
}{\newcommand\myfourthcommand}%
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\show\myfirstcommand
\show\mysecondcommand
\show\mythirdcommand
\show\myfourthcommand
\stop
```